# derivative chain-rules in fractional calculus

Tags: calculus

Consider the function $u(t,x)$ ;$(t,x)$ in $(0,1)\times(0,1)$;
we use the change of variable $u(t,x)=v(t,y)$ with $y=\frac{x}{t^\alpha}$, $0< \alpha <1$.
How can we calculate the caputo fractional partial derivative of $v$ with respect to the time variable $t$?